# Trouble running python script

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a proof-of-concept script that demonstrates a man-in-the-middle TLS negotiation exploit.  The trouble is, the script is written in Python and I have zero experience with Python.

The script is here: http://www.redteam-pentesting.de/files/tls-renegotiation-poc.py

The first error I received was about importing tlslite.  I downloaded this module:

http://trevp.net/tlslite/tlslite-0.3.8.tar.gz

Tlslite came with an installer that required Python 2.4, so I installed that version.  After that I was able to execute the script and even debug.  However, I'm stuck now.  I run this:

```
python.exe tls-renegotiation-poc.py -l 80 -b 127.0.0.1 -t encrypted.google.com:443 -i test
```

Then I go to 127.0.0.1 in FireFox.  I think get this error in Python:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python24\lib\threading.py", line 442, in __bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "E:\Python24\lib\threading.py", line 422, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\tls-renegotiation-poc.py", line 210, in handle_victim
    sslsock.handshakeClientCert(settings = handshake_settings)
  File "E:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\tlslite\TLSConnection.py", line 207, in handshakeClientCert
    for result in handshaker:
  File "E:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\tlslite\TLSConnection.py", line 369, in _handshakeClientAsync
    for result in self._handshakeWrapperAsync(handshaker, checker):
  File "E:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\tlslite\TLSConnection.py", line 1537, in _handshakeWrapperAsync
    for result in handshaker:
  File "E:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\tlslite\TLSConnection.py", line 399, in _handshakeClientAsyncHelper
    settings = settings._filter()
  File "E:\Python24\lib\site-packages\tlslite\HandshakeSettings.py", line 143, in _filter
    raise ValueError("minVersion set incorrectly")
ValueError: minVersion set incorrectly
```

This is my HandshakeSettings.py file (in case it helps):

```
"""Class for setting handshake parameters."""

from constants import CertificateType
from utils import cryptomath
from utils import cipherfactory

class HandshakeSettings:
    """This class encapsulates various parameters that can be used with
    a TLS handshake.
    @sort: minKeySize, maxKeySize, cipherNames, certificateTypes,
    minVersion, maxVersion

    @type minKeySize: int
    @ivar minKeySize: The minimum bit length for asymmetric keys.

    If the other party tries to use SRP, RSA, or Diffie-Hellman
    parameters smaller than this length, an alert will be
    signalled.  The default is 1023.

    @type maxKeySize: int
    @ivar maxKeySize: The maximum bit length for asymmetric keys.

    If the other party tries to use SRP, RSA, or Diffie-Hellman
    parameters larger than this length, an alert will be signalled.
    The default is 8193.

    @type cipherNames: list
    @ivar cipherNames: The allowed ciphers, in order of preference.

    The allowed values in this list are 'aes256', 'aes128', '3des', and
    'rc4'.  If these settings are used with a client handshake, they
    determine the order of the ciphersuites offered in the ClientHello
    message.

    If these settings are used with a server handshake, the server will
    choose whichever ciphersuite matches the earliest entry in this
    list.

    NOTE:  If '3des' is used in this list, but TLS Lite can't find an
    add-on library that supports 3DES, then '3des' will be silently
    removed.

    The default value is ['aes256', 'aes128', '3des', 'rc4'].

    @type certificateTypes: list
    @ivar certificateTypes: The allowed certificate types, in order of
    preference.

    The allowed values in this list are 'x509' and 'cryptoID'.  This
    list is only used with a client handshake.  The client will
    advertise to the server which certificate types are supported, and
    will check that the server uses one of the appropriate types.

    NOTE:  If 'cryptoID' is used in this list, but cryptoIDlib is not
    installed, then 'cryptoID' will be silently removed.

    @type minVersion: tuple
    @ivar minVersion: The minimum allowed SSL/TLS version.

    This variable can be set to (3,0) for SSL 3.0, (3,1) for
    TLS 1.0, or (3,2) for TLS 1.1.  If the other party wishes to
    use a lower version, a protocol_version alert will be signalled.
    The default is (3,0).

    @type maxVersion: tuple
    @ivar maxVersion: The maximum allowed SSL/TLS version.

    This variable can be set to (3,0) for SSL 3.0, (3,1) for
    TLS 1.0, or (3,2) for TLS 1.1.  If the other party wishes to
    use a higher version, a protocol_version alert will be signalled.
    The default is (3,2).  (WARNING: Some servers may (improperly)
    reject clients which offer support for TLS 1.1.  In this case,
    try lowering maxVersion to (3,1)).
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.minKeySize = 1023
        self.maxKeySize = 8193
        self.cipherNames = ["aes256", "aes128", "3des", "rc4"]
        self.cipherImplementations = ["cryptlib", "openssl", "pycrypto",
                                      "python"]
        self.certificateTypes = ["x509", "cryptoID"]
        self.minVersion = (3,0)
        self.maxVersion = (3,2)

    #Filters out options that are not supported
    def _filter(self):
        other = HandshakeSettings()
        other.minKeySize = self.minKeySize
        other.maxKeySize = self.maxKeySize
        other.cipherNames = self.cipherNames
        other.cipherImplementations = self.cipherImplementations
        other.certificateTypes = self.certificateTypes
        other.minVersion = self.minVersion
        other.maxVersion = self.maxVersion

        if not cipherfactory.tripleDESPresent:
            other.cipherNames = [e for e in self.cipherNames if e != "3des"]
        if len(other.cipherNames)==0:
            raise ValueError("No supported ciphers")

        try:
            import cryptoIDlib
        except ImportError:
            other.certificateTypes = [e for e in self.certificateTypes \
                                      if e != "cryptoID"]
        if len(other.certificateTypes)==0:
            raise ValueError("No supported certificate types")

        if not cryptomath.cryptlibpyLoaded:
            other.cipherImplementations = [e for e in \
                self.cipherImplementations if e != "cryptlib"]
        if not cryptomath.m2cryptoLoaded:
            other.cipherImplementations = [e for e in \
                other.cipherImplementations if e != "openssl"]
        if not cryptomath.pycryptoLoaded:
            other.cipherImplementations = [e for e in \
                other.cipherImplementations if e != "pycrypto"]
        if len(other.cipherImplementations)==0:
            raise ValueError("No supported cipher implementations")

        if other.minKeySize<512:
            raise ValueError("minKeySize too small")
        if other.minKeySize>16384:
            raise ValueError("minKeySize too large")
        if other.maxKeySize<512:
            raise ValueError("maxKeySize too small")
        if other.maxKeySize>16384:
            raise ValueError("maxKeySize too large")
        for s in other.cipherNames:
            if s not in ("aes256", "aes128", "rc4", "3des"):
                raise ValueError("Unknown cipher name: '%s'" % s)
        for s in other.cipherImplementations:
            if s not in ("cryptlib", "openssl", "python", "pycrypto"):
                raise ValueError("Unknown cipher implementation: '%s'" % s)
        for s in other.certificateTypes:
            if s not in ("x509", "cryptoID"):
                raise ValueError("Unknown certificate type: '%s'" % s)

        if other.minVersion > other.maxVersion:
            raise ValueError("Versions set incorrectly")

        if not other.minVersion in ((3,0), (3,1), (3,2)):
            raise ValueError("minVersion set incorrectly")

        if not other.maxVersion in ((3,0), (3,1), (3,2)):
            raise ValueError("maxVersion set incorrectly")

        return other

    def _getCertificateTypes(self):
        l = []
        for ct in self.certificateTypes:
            if ct == "x509":
                l.append(CertificateType.x509)
            elif ct == "cryptoID":
                l.append(CertificateType.cryptoID)
            else:
                raise AssertionError()
        return l
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?  I feel like it may be a simple answer, but my unfamiliarity with Python is making this difficult for me.  Thank you.

**UPDATE:** After changing the exception to this:

```
raise ValueError("minversion set incorrectly (%s)" % repr(other.minVersion))
```

I now get this:

```
ValueError: minversion set incorrectly ((69, 84))
```

Comment: please ask in http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: change 'if not other.minVersion in ((3,0), (3,1), (3,2)):
            raise ValueError("minVersion set incorrectly")', change the raise statement to 'raise ValueError("minversion set incorrectly (%s)" % repr(other.minversion))' and let us know what you get

Comment: @Udi, codereview is for code that works but needs improvement. this doesn't work, so it's in the right place.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx, added the results to the bottom of the original post for posterity.  The result was:ValueError: minversion set incorrectly ((69, 84))

Comment: those (69, 84) are ASCII values for "ET". somewhere other.minversion is being set to that. you'll have to grep through the code for minversion and see what and why this is happening.

Comment: It looks like it happens on line 188 of tls-renegotation.poc.py.  It's setting tls_version = (msg_version_major, msg_version_minor). I think Line 183 is where msg_version_major and msg_version_minor are set in function recv_clienthello via struct.unpack.  However, I don't think I'm savvy enough at Python to figure this out quickly, so I may try to step through it more in depth tomorrow.  I'll leave this question open-ended for now in case someone has some insight that could save me some trouble.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try `print`ing `other.minVersion` in `filter`: It looks like the input is not what you expect (i.e. you are expecting one of three tuples `[(3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2)] - but that isn't what you're recieving.

I often find that when throwing an error about a value outside a range like you are doing, that it is a good idea to include the offending value in the message. That would add more information to the error you are getting!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure what to expect here; I'm not sure what the expected inputs/outputs are.  I'm just trying to get this proof-of-concept code working as intended.  Could that version of tlslite be wrong?

Comment: Also, I amended the bottom of my original post with the value other.minVersion.  I should also say that before creating this post, I tried deleting that check, but that resulted in further errors.